# getting alternative routes from openstreetmaps

Tags: android, openstreetmap

i'm developing a android application which will detect traffic jams and map on openstreetmaps.in navigating between my current location and the destination if a traffic jam is detected the application should suggest all the other alternative routes.how can i get these alternative routes from openstreetmaps.

[image]

A1 - alternative route 1,
A2 - alternative route 2

Answer (score 0):

Some of the [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) have an *avoid areas* feature.

Comment: can you please share a code where avoid areas feature is used ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

GraphHopper allows you to make the routing influenced by traffic information. I've blogged recently about it [here](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/visualize-and-handle-traffic-information-with-graphhopper-in-real-time-for-cologne-germany-koln/).

Or you can just block certain streets with the blocking weighting described [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/weighting.md).